# ASP.NET Core запрос

Tags: c#, linq

Есть запрос следующего плана:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Ref(RefModel model)
    {
        var countreward = from c in db.Person
                            join g in db.Referal
                            on c.AccountID equals g.memb___id into gg
                            from ggg in gg.DefaultIfEmpty()

                            where ggg.referal_reward >= 1
                            where c.RCount >= 1


                            orderby c.AccountID == User.Identity.Name

                            select new Person()
                            {
                                AccountID = c.AccountID,
                                Name = c.Name,
                            };
        var reward = countreward.ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (reward.Count >= 1)
            {
                CSData bonus = db.CSData.First(p => p.AccountID == User.Identity.Name);
                bonus.GP+= 10 * reward.Count;

                db.CashShopData.Update(bonus);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                ViewBag.Message = "Да";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Нет";
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

После нажатия на кнопку я получаю всех нужных мне рефералов из таблицы Referal, сравниваю логин их по нужному критерию с таблицей Person и после этого получаю +=10 к своему логину. А теперь вопрос: как мне отправить +=5 тем, за кого я получил +=10?

Comment: `я получаю всех нужных мне рефералов`, `после этого получаю +=10 к своему логину` - берите логины рефералов, что у вас уже есть, и добавляйте им +5 тем же способом, что добавляете себе 10

Comment: Так я же получил список. Оператор == нельзя применить к string. CSData bonus2 = db.CSData.First(p => p.AccountID == reward); bonus2.GP+= 5;

Comment: `AccountID == reward` подумайте о том, что и с чем вы тут сравниваете

Comment: В этом и вопрос. Я не пойму как сравнить, новичок...

Comment: ну вы существующий код же как то написали? Значит, понимаете, как он работает. А там есть все, что вам надо для решения вашей задачи. Проблему в вашей попытке решить, я вам указал. Так что вперед :)

Comment: В том то и дело, что как-то))). Примеры на "Метаните".

Comment: если вы просто бездумно копипастите код с интернета, то тут вам не помогут и за вас задачи решать не будут. Если взялись изучать тему, то сперва поработайте над ней (там не сложно, поверьте), поймите, что делает каждая строчка кода из примера и зачем она нужна, после чего попробуйте сами решить свою задачу, и когда не получится - приходите с конкретной проблемой в коде, а не просто желанием добавить новый функционал. Если вы сами не стараетесь решать свои проблемы - то зачем кому то вам помогать?